# How do I take a vector input using command line argument?

Tags: c++, vector, command-line-arguments

I am not familiar with using command line arguments. I am trying to take a vector input as a command line argument. Please refer the below code and help me with the error.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    vector<int> arr;
    cout<<"Arguments are:\n";
    for(int i = 1 ; i < argc ; i++){
        arr.push_back(argv[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

The code is giving below error.

[image]

Comment: You want to have `vector<std::string> arr;` there, not `vector<int> arr;`. Also stop doing [`#include<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) please.

Comment: or a function (as [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)) to convert the `char*` into `int`.

Comment: Post error message as text first. (additional image/link might be fine).

Comment: You can use the vector constructor: `vector<std::string> arr(argv + 1, argv + argc);` instead of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your vector contains `int`s, but the command line arguments are strings (see error).
You should convert the `argv[i]` to `int`, than use the `push_back()`.
You can use `stoi()` which converts string to `int`, but keep in mind that it could happen when not just digits appear in the command line argument.